# Performing computer vision and machine learning on images saved on a database

Tags: database, image-processing, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am working on a website where users can crop a specific part of an image to be identified (e.g. company logos). The cropped image is submitted to a database to be identified by an internal system using machine learning techniques.

My problem is that I don't know where to start as I have no experience in the field of computer vision or machine learning. Here's what I would like to achieve as a start:

1. Extract features from user's cropped image as test dataset

   - What is the 'form' of the features? Is it an array of numbers?
   - What kind of database should I use for this purpose?
2. Implement machine learning algorithms on the server side

   - How do I 'embed' or offload the processing parts?
   - Which language would be relevant for this purpose?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to get familiar with one of the Computer Vision libraries such as [OpenCV](http://opencv.org).  It has what you need, including the implementation of machine learning algorithms.